# How add trend line to geom_bar with facet_wrap in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a trend line over to see the trend over the various quarters when divided by the geographical locations. This is the plot to which I would like to add the trendline.

```
Quart <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" )
Locate <- c("US", "Other", "US", "US", "Other", "US", "US", "Other")
Product_Price <- c(10, 25, 36, 153, 23, 20, 96, 785)
Product_ID <- c("helme[enter image description here][1]t", "gloves", "jacket", "helmet", "jacket", "glasses", "hoody", "gloves")
df <- data.frame (Quart, Locate, Product_ID, Product_Price)
df$Quart <- as.factor(df$Quart)
df$Locate <- as.factor(df$Locate)

#Price data Over Quarters by Location
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = df$Quart, y = df$Product_Price, fill = Locate)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
        labs(x = "Quarter", y="Product Price", title = "Price over Quarter and Location") +
        scale_fill_hue(name="Product Type") +
        facet_wrap(~Locate)
```

Comment: I don't think so - this plot is a bar chart, while the suspect duplicate is a scatterplot (or at least it mentions points), so this one may be asking for something slightly different.

Comment: On that note: What exactly do you want your line to be like? Should y coordinates of its points be the same as the height of individual bars?

Comment: Yes, I would like the trend line to be showing the difference from the highest value of the bar or it could be showing the difference between the average for the different quarters, located in each facet.

Comment: Do you want `geom_smooth(aes(x = as.numeric(Quart)), method = "lm", se = F)` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so! Would you also be able to help me get the line that shows the trend of the average.

Comment: `geom_smooth(aes(x = as.numeric(Quart)), method = "lm", formula = y ~ 1, se = F)`

Comment: Cool, thank you cuttlefish!